# « Se /nous donner des nouvelles » ou « se /nous donner des nouvelles l’un l’autre » ?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Laquelle des formulations suivantes est de meilleure langue? N’hésitez pas, en complément, à me donner des variantes d’un autre style.

> Quant à ta question, je réponds que oui, il serait agréable d’aller au cinéma ensemble pour regarder Avatar. Nous pourrions aussi, à cette occasion, en profiter pour

…**se** donner des nouvelles. (1)

…**nous** donner des nouvelles. (2)

…**se** donner des nouvelles **l’un l’autre.** (3)

…**nous** donner des nouvelles **l’un l’autre.** (4)

…**se** donner **de nos** nouvelles. (5)

…**nous** donner **de nos** nouvelles. (6)

…**se** donner **mutuellement de nos** nouvelles. (7)

…**nous** donner **mutuellement de nos** nouvelles. (8)

Sinon, serait-ce préférable d’exprimer l’idée autrement et de plutôt écrire quelque chose du genre

« Je pourrais aussi, à cette occasion, te donner de mes nouvelles et toi en faire autant .»?

Comment: « … se passer un coup d'fil. » « … se tenir au courant. »

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dans sa définition le Larousse fait état de nouvelles en tant que renseignements.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nouvelles/55125)) 1. Renseignements d'ordre privé donnés sur quelqu'un, sur une famille que l'on connaît.
> • Donnez-nous régulièrement de vos nouvelles.

On retrouve ce point essentiel dans le TLFi, mais il s'y trouve une addition importante : ces  renseignements concernent une personne que l'on n'a pas vue récemment.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nouvelles)) **B.** − Gén. au plur.
>
> 1. Renseignements concernant la situation, l'état de santé d'une personne que l'on n'a pas vue récemment.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nouvelle)) Renseignement sur l’état d’une personne ou d’une chose dont on n’était pas informé depuis quelque temps.

Les nouvelles ne sont pas des éléments d'un entretien en eux-mêmes mais certains de ces éléments en tant que renseignements sur ce qui a pu arriver à quelqu'un que l'on n'a pas vue récemment.

Lorsque l'on rencontre quelqu'un on peut dire « Je viens prendre de tes/vos nouvelles.  », mais on ne dira pas « Je viens te/vous voir pour que tu/vous me donnes/donniez de tes/vos nouvelles.  »; on ne dit pas non plus au début ou au milieu  d'un entretien « Donnes-moi de tes nouvelles. » : on parle et ce que l'on apprend sur la personne donnée devient des renseignements, des nouvelles ; passer outre ce principe équivaudrait à peu près à dire « donne-moi des renseignements sur ta vie dernièrement.  » et le ton d'une telle requête relève trop de celui d'une procédure formelle, ce qui tend à expliquer que ça ne se fait pas. Si on dit « Donnes-moi de tes nouvelles. », il s'agit d'une requête de faire ce qui est demander durant la période qui va suivre la visite donnée ou le coup de téléphone. On peut, à la rigueur, s'introduire dans une conversation avec quelqu'un que l'on n'a pas vu depuis longtemps par une phrase telle que « Je viens prendre de tes/vos nouvelles.  », ce qui est quand même contradictoire. Lorsqu'on vient prendre des nouvelles de quelqu'un, au moment où on  veut avoir des renseignement, il faut aborder ces investigations fifféremment ; on peut dire parmi un choix de nombreuse façons de s'exprimer des chose comme « Racontes-moi comment se sont passées les choses pour toi ces derniers temps. » ou pour qui veut être badin (d'une manière qui n'est pas nécessairement du gout de tout le monde pour ce qui est de celle-ci), « Alors, qu'est-ce qui t'est arrivé de beau ces derniers temps ? ». De même, en parlant à quelqu'un que l'on n'a pas vu depuis un certain temps, que ce soit au téléphone ou dans une conversation en face à face, on n'introduit pas des faits que l'on va raconter sur ce que l'on vient de vivre par des phrases qui contiennent la locution « de  mes nouvelles ».

(*Non utilisé dans les dialogues*)

- Il faut que je te donne de mes nouvelles. [suit « récit constituant des nouvelles  »]
- Voilà un aperçu de mes nouvelles. [suit « récit constituant des nouvelles  »]
- Et si je te donnais de mes nouvelles un peu ? [suit « récit constituant des nouvelles  »]
  etc.

Cette discussion devrait situer un peu mieux l'usage du mot  « nouvelles  ».

D'une telle rencontre, au cinéma,  après ne pas avoir communiqué pendant longtemps, va résulter des nouvelles dont on pourra faire part à d'autres connaissances en tant que nouvelles ou auquelles on pourra référer, en d'autres termes, comme renseignements qui suivent après une perte de vue assez longue. On ne dirait donc  pas normalement les phrases  « 1 » à « 8 ».

Comment alors exprimer l'idée que l'on peut lire dans ces formulations inadéquates ? Eh bien on pourrait par exemple, et le plus simplement possible, utiliser une expression qui « inclut » les nouvelles.

- Quant à ta question, je réponds que oui, il serait agréable d’aller au cinéma ensemble pour regarder Avatar. Nous pourrions aussi, à cette occasion, en profiter pour nous raconter nos vies.

*Autre cas*

—  (*Jean*) Tu as des nouvelles de Josef ?
— (*Jacques*) Il nous rend visite tous les jours, pourquoi, tu ne le vois plus ?

La réponse de Jacques pourrait être « oui », mais elle ne correspond pas à la situation parce qu'on pourrait comprendre que l'interlocuteur lui non plus n'a pas vu Joseph depuis Longtemps. Ce que Jacques va dire à Jean à propos de Josef sont des nouvelles pour Jean, mais pas pour Jacques.

Answer (score 2):

> **On** pourrait aussi, à cette occasion, en profiter pour **se** donner de nos nouvelles (respectives).

> Je pourrais aussi, à cette occasion, te donner de mes nouvelles, et réciproquement.